# Asymptotic behaviour of Green's function in real space

Tags: solid-state-physics, scattering, greens-functions, scattering-cross-section, asymptotics

It is well known that in $k$-space, a Green's function usually has asymptotic behaviour $\frac{1}{\omega}$ as $\omega \to \infty$. Are there any similar result in position space? This idea is inspired by considering the Green's function of free electron gas:
$$
G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r^\prime}) = -\frac{m}{2\pi\hbar^2}\frac{e^{ik|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|}\to\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}e^{-ik\hat{r}r^\prime}
$$
when $\mathbf{r}\to\infty$.
This result is very useful in deriving the scattering cross section of free electrons. I'm now considering about a similar problem in sold where the Green's function can be written as (Bloch Representation):
$$
G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r^\prime})=\int\mathrm{d}\mathbf{k}\frac{\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})\psi^*_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r^{\prime}})}{\epsilon-\epsilon_\mathbf{k}+i0^+}
$$

I think it may be useful to do some asymptotic analysis on this Green's function.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296547/84967

Comment: Wouldn't MSE be more suited for this kind of question?

Comment: The Bloch form is a periodic function base. You cannot perform an asymptotic expansion in r-space. Or you are looking for large energy behavior (through a Fourier transformation) as suggested in the first comment, large $p$ behavior.

Comment: @ytlu Yes, if I translate both $r$ and $r^\prime$ by a lattice vector, the green's function does not change. This is also happen in free electron case. However, if I fix $r^\prime$ and let $r$ to infinity, then the green's function is not periodic. There is always a $e^{ikR}$ factors appear in the integrals. Maybe there are some asymptotic behaviours in this case? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Xzy In the above first Greens's function, there has $1/r_{12}$ to diminish the function for large $r_{12}$, but not in the 2$_{nd}$ form. Without the  $1/r_{12}$ factor, it is still an periodic function of $\vec r'$ for a fixed $\vec r$.